# Undefined property: stdClass::$id for laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I was doing this on laravel using query builder for API

```
$shipments = DB::table('shipment_batches')
            ->select(
                "shipments.id as shipment_id",
                "shipments.fulfillment_id",
                "shipments.shipped_address_id",
                "shipments.courrier_id",
                "shipments.status",
                "shipments.is_intro",
                "shipments.is_express",
                "shipments.shipment_batch_id",
                "shipments.intro_shipment_date",
                "shipments.intro_shipped_at",
                "shipments.tracking_number",
                "shipments.is_gift",
                "shipments.ship_unit",
                "shipments.shipment_notes",
                "shipments.is_one_time_product",
                "shipments.one_time_product_shipment_date",
                "shipments.one_time_product_shipped_at",
                "shipments.shipment_options",
                "shipments.is_migrated",
                "shipments.migration_has_error",
                "shipments.in_process_date",
                "shipments.shipment_date_at",
                "shipments.link",
                )
            ->join('shipments', 'shipments.shipment_batch_id', '=', 'shipment_batches.id')
            ->join('fulfillments', 'fulfillments.id', '=', 'shipments.fulfillment_id')
            ->join('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.id', '=', 'fulfillments.subscription_id')
            ->whereMonth('shipment_batches.shipment_date', '>', date('m'))
            ->whereYear('shipment_batches.shipment_date', '=', date('Y'))
            ->where('subscriptions.user_id', $id)
            ->orderBy('shipment_batches.id', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        return UpcomingShipmentsResource::collection($shipments);
```

And I have this resource collection

```
class UpcomingShipmentsResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id"  => $this->id,
            "hashed_id" => hashids_encode($this->id),
            "padded_id" => id_padder($this->id),
        ];
    }
}
```

I just removed other array return values to simplify the collection.
and added `hashed_id` and `padded_id` to modify the result before returning as json on API

I got this error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Is it possible to create collection out of query builder?
How?

Answer (score 1):

In query select:

```
->select(
                "shipments.id as shipment_id",
                "shipments.fulfillment_id",
                "shipments.shipped_address_id",
                "shipments.courrier_id",
                "shipments.status",
                "shipments.is_intro",
                "shipments.is_express",
                "shipments.shipment_batch_id",
                "shipments.intro_shipment_date",
                "shipments.intro_shipped_at",
                "shipments.tracking_number",
                "shipments.is_gift",
                "shipments.ship_unit",
                "shipments.shipment_notes",
                "shipments.is_one_time_product",
                "shipments.one_time_product_shipment_date",
                "shipments.one_time_product_shipped_at",
                "shipments.shipment_options",
                "shipments.is_migrated",
                "shipments.migration_has_error",
                "shipments.in_process_date",
                "shipments.shipment_date_at",
                "shipments.link",
                )
```

You are not selecting "id", so you won't have "$this->id" in toArray() method.

You should add:

```
->select(
    "tablename.id as id",
    ...
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$shipments = DB::table('shipment_batches')
            ->select(
                "shipments.id as id",
                "shipments.id as shipment_id",
                "shipments.fulfillment_id",
                "shipments.shipped_address_id",
                "shipments.courrier_id",
                "shipments.status",
                "shipments.is_intro",
                "shipments.is_express",
                "shipments.shipment_batch_id",
                "shipments.intro_shipment_date",
                "shipments.intro_shipped_at",
                "shipments.tracking_number",
                "shipments.is_gift",
                "shipments.ship_unit",
                "shipments.shipment_notes",
                "shipments.is_one_time_product",
                "shipments.one_time_product_shipment_date",
                "shipments.one_time_product_shipped_at",
                "shipments.shipment_options",
                "shipments.is_migrated",
                "shipments.migration_has_error",
                "shipments.in_process_date",
                "shipments.shipment_date_at",
                "shipments.link",
                )
            ->join('shipments', 'shipments.shipment_batch_id', '=', 'shipment_batches.id')
            ->join('fulfillments', 'fulfillments.id', '=', 'shipments.fulfillment_id')
            ->join('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.id', '=', 'fulfillments.subscription_id')
            ->whereMonth('shipment_batches.shipment_date', '>', date('m'))
            ->whereYear('shipment_batches.shipment_date', '=', date('Y'))
            ->where('subscriptions.user_id', $id)
            ->orderBy('shipment_batches.id', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        return UpcomingShipmentsResource::collection($shipments);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please don't code-dump - maybe format it nicely, and add an explanation or comments as to how and why your code works and solves the problem.